# Extracting data from PGN files

Tags: python, python-chess

I trying to extract move information and annotations from a few PGN files, outputting to a text file. My current code is:

```
import chess.pgn
import io
import os


def handle_san_error(pgn_file, game_str, san_error):
    # Skip the problematic move
    lines = game_str.splitlines()
    problematic_move = str(san_error).split()[2].strip("'")
    new_lines = [line for line in lines if problematic_move not in line]

    # Print the problematic move and file
    print(f"Error in file: {pgn_file}")
    print(f"Problematic move: {problematic_move}")

    return "\n".join(new_lines)

def process_pgn_files(pgn_files, output_file):
    with open(output_file, 'w') as out_file:
        first_game = True
        for pgn_file in pgn_files:
            print(f"Processing file: {pgn_file}")  # Print the current file being processed
            with open(pgn_file) as file:
                game_str = file.read()
                game_io = io.StringIO(game_str)

                while True:
                    try:
                        game_io.seek(0)
                        game = chess.pgn.read_game(game_io)
                        if game is None:
                            break
                    except chess.IllegalMoveError as e:
                        game_str = handle_san_error(pgn_file, game_str, e)  # Pass the pgn_file to the function
                        game_io = io.StringIO(game_str)
                        continue

                    node = game
                    error_in_game = False

                    while not node.is_end():
                        move = node.move

                        if move is None:
                            error_in_game = True
                            break

                        if not first_game:
                            out_file.write('===\n')
                        else:
                            first_game = False

                        out_file.write(str(move) + '\n')

                        if node.comment:
                            out_file.write(node.comment.strip() + '\n')

                        out_file.write('\n')

                        node = node.next()

                    if error_in_game:
                        break

pgn_directory = 'directory'
output_file = 'output.txt'

pgn_files = [os.path.join(pgn_directory, f) for f in os.listdir(pgn_directory) if f.endswith('.pgn')]

process_pgn_files(pgn_files, output_file)
```

I want the output to look like this:

1.d4 f5

The Dutch Defense

2.Nf3 e6 3.Nc3

Blocking his c-pawn, White aims for rapid development and the central break, e2-e4.

3...Nf6 4. Bg5 Be7 5. Bxf6

White exchanges in order to break with e2-e4. The inherent problem with the Dutch Defense is the early weakening of the kingside with 1...f5.

5...Bxf6 6. e4

White is missing his dark-squared Bishop. Recommended for Black is 6...d5, which forces White to clarify his intentions in the center.

6...fxe4

Not best, as it activates White's QN.

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
def process_pgn_files(pgn_files, output_file):
    with open(output_file, 'w') as out_file:
        first_game = True
        for pgn_file in pgn_files:
            print(f"Processing file: {pgn_file}")  # Print the current file being processed
            with open(pgn_file) as file:
                game_str = file.read()
                game_io = io.StringIO(game_str)

                while True:
                    try:
                        game_io.seek(0)
                        game = chess.pgn.read_game(game_io)
                        if game is None:
                            break
                    except chess.IllegalMoveError as e:
                        game_str = handle_san_error(pgn_file, game_str, e)  # Pass the pgn_file to the function
                        game_io = io.StringIO(game_str)
                        continue

                    node = game
                    error_in_game = False
                    commentary = ""

                    while not node.is_end():
                        move = node.move

                        if move is None:
                            error_in_game = True
                            break

                        if not first_game:
                            out_file.write('===\n')
                        else:
                            first_game = False

                        out_file.write(str(move) + ' ')

                        if node.comment:
                            commentary += node.comment.strip() + ' '

                        node = node.next()

                    if commentary:
                        out_file.write('\n\n' + commentary.strip() + '\n\n')

                    if error_in_game:
                        break
```

Let's create new `commentary string to hold all the annotations for the current move. Inside the while loop append the current node's comment to the commentary string, separated by a space. After the loop check if there is any commentary and if so write it to the output file, separated by two newlines.